# Валидация множества форм на странице ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте. У меня появилась необходимость сделать регистрацию и вход на одной странице. Но дело в том, что я не знаю, как сделать задать модель для каждой формы, чтобы можно было провести валидацию. Я думаю, что у многих была такая проблема. Кто как решал?

Comment: > как сделать задать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решить вашу проблему помогут **PartialView**. Сделайте две отдельных partial view, в которых будут формы для входа и регистрации. У каждой из них, естественно, будут свои модели, с нужными вам валидационными правилами. После этого останется только отрендерить эти вьюшки на нужной странице.

[Здесь](http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/) неплохой учебный пример, однако на английском.